# How to truss the combined commands via some predefined variable?

Tags: shell, truss

If we use the combined commands directly in the truss arguments, it works fine without any problems.

However, if we use the predefined variable of the combined commands indirectly in the truss arguments, it fails.

```
# 
# truss -adefo /tmp/not_a_term.out  ls -ltr|head
total 233888
drwx------    2 root     system          256 Feb 22 2017  lost+found
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          406 Feb 22 2017  .sr_migrate.log
-rw-------    1 root     system            0 Feb 22 2017  .strload.mutex
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          708 Feb 22 2017  ctrmc_MDdr.dbg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          708 Feb 22 2017  IBM.CSMAgentRM_dr.sh.dbg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system         9114 Feb 23 2017  .tzlist
d-w-------    2 root     system          256 Feb 23 2017  saved_errmbatch
d-w-------    2 root     system          256 Feb 23 2017  errmbatch
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          179 Feb 23 2017  mirror_1.out
#            
# 
# 
# A1="ls -ltr|head"                             
# 
# 
# truss -adefo /tmp/not_a_term.out  $A1         
ls: Not a recognized flag: |
ls: Not a recognized flag: h
Usage: ls [-1ACFHLNRSabcdefgiklmnopqrstuxEUX] [File...]
# 
#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we found that the similar demand function must be run via a script that including these multiple combined commands.
Note: it seems that the truss command can accept only one "external" command as argv once, versus multiple "internal" commands as argc.

```
#
# 
# truss -adefo /tmp/not_a_term.out  ls -ltr|head
total 233888
drwx------    2 root     system          256 Feb 22 2017  lost+found
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          406 Feb 22 2017  .sr_migrate.log
-rw-------    1 root     system            0 Feb 22 2017  .strload.mutex
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          708 Feb 22 2017  ctrmc_MDdr.dbg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          708 Feb 22 2017  IBM.CSMAgentRM_dr.sh.dbg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system         9114 Feb 23 2017  .tzlist
d-w-------    2 root     system          256 Feb 23 2017  saved_errmbatch
d-w-------    2 root     system          256 Feb 23 2017  errmbatch
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          179 Feb 23 2017  mirror_1.out
# 
# 
# wc -l /tmp/not_a_term.out
     595 /tmp/not_a_term.out
# 
# 
# grep head /tmp/not_a_term.out
# 
# 
# grep -E "arg|execve"   /tmp/not_a_term.out
25296928: 0.0000:        execve("/usr/bin/ls", 0x2FF22C6C, 0x200132F8)  argc: 2
25296928: 64291025:  argv: ls -ltr 
# 
# 
# 
# echo "ls -ltr|head  >t_2 2>&1" > l_h.sh
# 
# 
# cat l_h.sh
ls -ltr|head  >t_2 2>&1
# 
# 
# chmod 744 l_h.sh
# 
# 
# truss -adefo /tmp/not_a_term.out ./l_h.sh
# 
# 
# grep -E "arg|execve" /tmp/not_a_term.out
28377090: 0.0000:        execve("./l_h.sh", 0x2FF22C70, 0x200132F8) Err#8  ENOEXEC
28377090: 69468411: 0.0138:        execve("/usr/bin/sh", 0xF07F8558, 0x200132F8)  argc: 3
28377090: 69468411:  argv: sh -- ./l_h.sh
25165906:       60555303: 0.0408:        execve("/usr/bin/ls", 0x200117A8, 0x200117D8)  argc: 2
25165906:       60555303:  argv: ls -ltr
25165906:       60555303: 0.0486:        execve("/usr/bin/head", 0x200117A8, 0x200117D8) = 0xD0539130  argc: 1
27131920:       64553157:  argv: head
# 
#
```

Answer (score 2):

You write

> If we use the combined commands directly in the truss arguments

But that sounds misleading. In the command:

```
truss -adefo /tmp/not_a_term.out  ls -ltr|head
```

the shell runs `truss` with the four arguments `-adefo`, `/tmp/not_a_term.out`, `ls` and `-ltr`. That pipeline to `head` there is not part of the arguments to `truss`, but is special shell syntax that leads the shell to run `head` concurrently with `truss`, with the stdout of `truss` connected to the stdin of `head`. Other than seeing its output go to a pipe, `truss` isn't aware that `head` is there.

In the other command:

```
truss -adefo /tmp/not_a_term.out  $A1
```

there is no pipeline. Instead, the shell runs `truss` with the arguments `-adefo`, `/tmp/not_a_term.out` and whatever `$A1` expands and splits to. With `A1="ls -ltr|head"` , that results in the arguments `-adefo`, `/tmp/not_a_term.out`, `ls` and `-ltr|head`. When `truss` eventually launches `ls`, `ls` notices it doesn't recognize the `|` as an option characters.

If you want to interpret the contents of a variable for shell syntax, you need to run it through `eval`, e.g.

```
A1="ls -ltr|head"
eval "truss -adefo /tmp/not_a_term.out $A1"
```

which first expands to `truss -adefo /tmp/not_a_term.out ls -ltr|head` and that is then parsed by the shell similarly to that very first command above.

Note that since there is an additional step of parsing, you need to be careful to quote any data properly. E.g. if you holding a filename in a variable, any shell syntax embedded in the name would be parsed. Consider:

```
file='$(date >&2)'
touch "$file"
# you now have a filename with a literal $ in it
# this runs 'ls' on the file
ls -ld "$file"
# this runs 'date' and 'ls -ld'
eval ls -ld "$file"
```

Depending on what exactly you want, you could e.g. create a function to run truss on some command and pipe the output through head, e.g. this would run the same pipeline:

```
trusshead() {
    outfile=$1
    shift
    truss -adefo "$outfile" "$@" | head
}
trusshead /tmp/not_a_term.out ls -ltr
```

Comment: My original intention is that the truss command itself can only take effect on one command (or one script) as its input arguments ...